# MS Chart - Chart type area- Backcolor issue

Tags: winforms, charts, mschart

[image]

I'm using ms charts in winforms.
Till now i'm able to create this chart. Now the problem is i want that reddish paint to be inside the area, it is now starting to paint from 0, so looking reverse of what i actually want.
This is my first question to stackoverflow, it may not be constructive but i will give more info if you ask.
Apologies and thanks.

Some part of Code:

```
ChartArea.YAxis.Maximum = 0;
ChartArea.YAxis.Minimum = -100;
ChartArea.YAxis.IsStartedFromZero = False;

Series tempSeries = chartSSIDDetails.Series.FindByName("Series1");
tempSeries.Points.AddXY(0, -100); tempSeries.Points.AddXY(1, -20); 
tempSeries.Points.AddXY(2, -20); tempSeries.Points.AddXY(3, -20);
tempSeries.Points.AddXY(4, -100);
```

[image: Series design]

There is nothing much than this. Please let me know anything else you need.

Comment: Without seeing the code which you've used it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Series tempSeries = chartSSIDDetails.Series.FindByName("Series1");
tempSeries.Points.AddXY(0, -100);
            tempSeries.Points.AddXY(1, -20);
            tempSeries.Points.AddXY(2, -20);
            tempSeries.Points.AddXY(3, -20);
            tempSeries.Points.AddXY(4, -100);


I have designed chart in designer. I will give code for it in minute,

Comment: Update you question don't put everything in comments.

Comment: The graph is negative, so you're coloring the the area between the curve and the axis. The picture is correct.

Comment: Can i still color it other way ? or any possible work around ?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graph is showing correct as per the code you have shown. 
As the values for Y axis are negative, graph is projected downwards 
(so you can see values are starting from 0 on Y-axis)

You will have to pass positive integers to Y-axis if you want to see it opposite way.
You can later customize label to show Y-axis values to negatives.